# Javascript password - remember the user's input

Tags: javascript, password-protection

I the following JS password script:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
var password;
var pass1="hello";
password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' ');
if (password==pass1 )
alert('Password Correct! Click OK to enter!');
else
{
window.location="test.html";
}
</SCRIPT>
```

I would like the password to be remebered in the pop-up box after the user enters it, whether it's right or wrong.

Or even... if a user enters a correct password the page 'remembers' (cookie) that the user has been successful and doesn't ask for a password again until the browser is closed down.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Just to confirm - this is not meant to be a real security mechanism, right? If this is for effect, by all means, go for it, but don't use this to gate actually secure content. I'm happy to provide alternate information if you're looking for real password authentication on a website.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is for an internal site where not proper security is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can store authorisation status in the cookies with:

```
document.cookie = 'authorized=1';
```

And later check it with:

```
if (document.cookie.match(/\bauthorized=1\b/))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Not secure, but seems it doesn't matter when password is stored in the page's source